# Best way to organize multiple Firebase apps sharing a database with separate authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm fairly new to Google Firebase and I am developing two apps that will be linked together. The apps will be using Firebase authentication, cloud functions, and firestore database.

For a simple use case let's assume one app is for admins and the other is for regular users. I want to have separate authentication (i.e. Admin can go to the user app and create a new user account using the same email address). But I also want them to be able to use the same Firestore database to access information. Lastly, I need to be able to call the same set of Cloud functions from both apps.

To summarize my needs:

- 2 apps
- Seperate Authentication (ability to have an account with same email on both apps. It is not really essential to have a different password - can be shared)
- Use same Firestore database
- Use same Cloud functions

I believe I have two options

(Complicated Option)

- 2 separate Firebase projects. Completely separate authentication. Point to same database. But unsure about making Cloud functions work and properly authenticating user

(Simpler Option)

- 1 Firebase project w/ multiple apps. When a new user is authenticated I would have to add a record to both "users" and "admins". Under "admins" the user would be disabled until a flag is manually changed (given admin permission) -- a bit annoying but I could make it work. This lets me share the same Firestore database and Cloud functions with minimal problems compared to the more complex solution.

Which option would be ideal for my use case? Are there other design choices I am not considering? (Note: I am using react-native to develop my apps (https://rnfirebase.io/))

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking here is largely a matter of opinion.  Neither one is definitely better than the other, given the details you've shared here.  I suggest picking the one that you simply feel more comfortable with.

The only part of this that doesn't involve any opinion is the fact that the Firebase-recommended approach to having more than one app whose users are **not** intended to overlap at all is to use multiple projects.  If you want the same set of users to apply equally to all apps, then you should use multiple apps per project.